# How to get the Chrome Browser cookie file path when it is launched from selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scan the cookies of a specific page with selenium.

Unfortunately, the `get_cookies()` method can only get the first-party cookies, but I am more interested in the 3rd party cookies. As far as I can see the easiest solution could be reading Cookies database file of the browser. I tested my idea with the normal chrome browser and it works fine, I can find the 3rd party cookies with all their details in this file - `\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`.

My problem that I can't figure out where the webdriver.chrome browser is saving the cookies on my local pc. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching chrome URL `chrome://appcache-internals/` will give app cache path. This gives a path from where the profile is loaded

So now we can use this trick in a browser launched in selenium and enter this URL. Will display the different profile path as shown in the image below.

[image]

When You navigate this path in your window file explorer you will get the browser profile stored in a path `\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir22252_1086323558\Default` where `scoped_dir22252_1086323558` is randomly created folder for each browser launch from selenium. Now you can get cookie file from this path

I hope this is your required output

You can automate this by launching the chrome URL `chrome://appcache-internals/` and get the cookie filepath. Read the cookie file using [SQLlite JDBC](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/select/) (since it is a SQLlite database) apply the SQL query and fetch the real data as you need

Comment: Jainam, thanks a lot for the very quick reply. It works perfectly